# Container structure issue with JQuery - Containing containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, structure

I'm finishing up a memory game for school and I'd really like the cards to flip with a CSS animation, which on it's own is pretty straight forward. However I'm pretty new to JavaScript and JQuery which is leading to some trouble with achieving the proper container structure I need to make the cards flip when they are clicked.

Presently the game pieces generate within the board as follows:

```
const generate=(cards)=>{
    cards.forEach(function(card, i) {
        $(".gameBoard") 
        .append($("<div>").addClass("front")// 
        .append($("<div>").addClass("back").append($("
         <img>").attr("src", cards[i]))));
    }); 
};
```

OR:

```
<div class="gameBoard>
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"><img src="cards"></div>
</div>
```

But in order for the animation to function properly  both the front and back divs need to exist in the same container like this:

```
<div class="gameBoard>
    <div class="flip">
          <div class="front></div>
          <div class="back"><img src="cards></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

How can I add the div I need (.flip) but have it contain the front and back divs, not just append on to the other divs being generated within the .gameboard container.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler to create your DOM using template literals rather than jQuery methods. That way you just describe the HTML as you're accustomed to.

```js
const generate=(cards)=>{
    cards.forEach(function(card, i) {
        $(".gameBoard").append(`
          <div class=flip>
            <div class=front></div>
            <div class=back><img src="${cards[i]}"</div>
          </div>
        `);
    }); 
};

generate([
  "https://dummyimage.com/180x120/f00/fff.png&text=one",
  "https://dummyimage.com/180x120/0f0/fff.png&text=two",
  "https://dummyimage.com/180x120/00f/fff.png&text=three",
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=gameBoard></div>
```

You'll notice the `${cards[i]}`, which lets you perform string interpolation by executing at runtime the code in the braces.

---

Here's a vanilla JS version.

```js
const generate=(cards)=>{
    var gb = document.querySelector(".gameBoard");
    cards.forEach(card =>
        gb.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
          <div class=flip>
            <div class=front></div>
            <div class=back><img src="${card}"</div>
          </div>
        `)
    ); 
};

generate([
  "https://dummyimage.com/180x120/f00/fff.png&text=one",
  "https://dummyimage.com/180x120/0f0/fff.png&text=two",
  "https://dummyimage.com/180x120/00f/fff.png&text=three",
]);
```

```html
<div class=gameBoard></div>
```

It also uses `card` instead of `cards[i]`, and an arrow function for the callback.

---

And this one performs a single append.

```js
const generate=(cards)=>{
    document.querySelector(".gameBoard")
      .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", cards.map(card =>
        ` <div class=flip>
            <div class=front></div>
            <div class=back><img src="${card}"</div>
          </div>`).join(""));
};

generate([
  "https://dummyimage.com/180x120/f00/fff.png&text=one",
  "https://dummyimage.com/180x120/0f0/fff.png&text=two",
  "https://dummyimage.com/180x120/00f/fff.png&text=three",
]);
```

```html
<div class=gameBoard></div>
```